# How can I find flight number and ticket number from a past flight one year ago?

Tags: jetblue

My family and I took a flight on Jet Blue last February and I need to find the flight number and ticket number so I can claim my points.

Comment: @JanDoggen Doesn't seem to be a duplicate. The information there might get the flight number but it won't help with the ticket number.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number hasn't changed - you could find that same flight on [Flight Radar 24](https://www.flightradar24.com) and it will tell you the number.